# what does this mean? " expected <td.top-aligned-table.ng-star-inserted> to exist in the DOM"

Tags: cypress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8ea9.png)i have test script test with assertion in the of end of the script and produce like my title in above

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean, but I'll explain your test result.

What you see is the that you asked Cypress to perform a 'get' on an element (specified with `.ui-datatable-data > nth-child(1) nth-ch...>`. When Cypress was looking for that specific element if found the element with class `<td.top-aligned-table.ng-star-inserted>`.
The `DOM` is the view of the browser, so basically the application which is tested. 
And Cypress expects the element to exist in the DOM since you performed a `cy.get()` on the element

Comment: actually I did not know that the elemet I was using assertion with exist was empty. actually, the data that I check is the data I just updated instead of create. There are some of the 9 elements that I stepped over / not updated. so I checked the results of the update I did on the existing data on the display.

anyway, about your comment, 
I have applied assertion to get the contents they contain. However, only the top two only have content even though before, all the elements on the display have been updated. where do you think it's wrong? or do I need to show the entire code?

Comment: see in my next comment. This bellow.

Answer (score 0):

[this the picture after i click button save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6tTJ.png)

this is the part of html code of the picture that i'm attached

[this is that i wanna test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L62fz.png)

after i click button save 
not visible in the picture, i wanna assert the result of my test `

i wanna update/edit test this part like this code. anyway, according to you, 
how bad is my code?. At the core of my code, there are some elements that I filled in and some of which I passed

```js
//file test runner 
exports.productupdate=function(product_update){
    cy.url().should('include','/invoicer/dashboard')
    
    cy.clearCookies()
    //assertion
    cy.get('.paywall-dropdown > .btn-group > #single-button > .hidden-xs').should('contain','Free')
    
    //cy.get('.close-button').click()
    
    //choose language -> ID
    cy.get('.language-dropdown').click()

    cy.get('.ui-dropdown-items-wrapper').contains('EN').click()
    
    cy.get('div .olark-top-bar-button').click({force:true})
    
    cy.get('.dropdown-toggle').contains("Product").click()
    
    //sub menunya 
    cy.get('.open > .child-dropdown > :nth-child(1) > .dropdown-item').contains("Product").click()
    
    //global variabel 
for(var i=0;i<product_update.length;i++){
    //tindakan Update 
    cy.get('.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle').contains("Action").click({force:true})
    
    cy.get('.dropdown-item').contains("Edit").click({force:true})

    //Product Name
    if(product_update[i].product_name != null){
        //assertion
        cy.get('.btn-input-form-data').should('contain', "SAVE")

        cy.get('[name|="namaValidation"]').click({multiple:true}).clear().type(product_update[i].product_name)
    }
    else{
        cy.get('[name|="namaValidation"]').click({force:true}).end()
    }
    //Product Code
    if(product_update[i].product_code != null){
        cy.get('[name|="kodeValidation"]').click({multiple:true}).clear().type(product_update[i].product_code)
    }
    else{
        cy.get('[name|="kodeValidation"]').click({multiple:true}).end()
    }

    //Unit
    if(product_update[i].unit != null){
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > div.ng-tns-c22-48 > .ng-tns-c22-48 > .ui-select-container > .ui-select-match > .btn').click({force:true})

        cy.get('.dropdown-item').contains(product_update[i].unit)
    }else{
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > div.ng-tns-c22-39 > .ng-tns-c22-39 > .ui-select-container > .ui-select-match > .btn').end()
    }

    //Product Category 
    if(product_update[i].product_category != null){
        cy.get(':nth-child(4) > div.ng-tns-c22-48 > .ng-tns-c22-48 > .ui-select-container > .ui-select-match > .btn-default').click({force:true})

        cy.get('.dropdown-item').contains(product_update[i].product_category).click({force:true})
    }else{
        cy.get(':nth-child(4) > div.ng-tns-c22-39 > .ng-tns-c22-39 > .ui-select-container > .ui-select-match > .btn-default').end()
    }

    //Purchase Price 
    if(product_update[i].purchase_price != null){
        cy.get('[name|="purchaseValidation"]').click({force:true}).clear().type(product_update[i].purchase_price)
    }else{
        cy.get('[name|="purchaseValidation"]').click({force:true}).end()
    }

    //sales Price
    if(product_update[i].sales_price != null){
        cy.get('[name|="hargaValidation"]').click({force:true}).clear().type(product_update[i].sales_price)
    }else{
        cy.get('[name|="hargaValidation"]').click({force:true}).end()
    }


    //description
    if(product_update[i].description != null){
        cy.get('[name|="descriptionValidation"]').click({force:true}).clear().type(product_update[i].description)
    }else{
        cy.get('[name|="descriptionValidation"]').click({force:true}).end()
    }
    // //jika di klik ga bisa di save
    // //stok 
    //  cy.get('.location-initial > ng-select.ng-tns-c23-40 > .ui-select-container > .ui-select-match > .btn').contains("Select a Stock Location").click()

    // cy.get('.ui-select-choices-row > .dropdown-item').contains(
    // product_update[i].update_stock).click({force:true})

    //button 
    cy.get('.btn-input-form-data[type="button"]').contains("SAVE").click({force:true})

    //ASSERTION after button save
    if(product_update[i].product_name == null) {
        cy.get('.ng-star-inserted').should('contain', '')
    }
    else{
        cy.get('.ng-star-inserted').should('contain', product_update[i].product_name)
    }
    if(product_update[i].product_code== null) {
        cy.get('.ui-datatable-data > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(2)').should('have.value', '')
    }
    else{
        cy.get('.top-aligned-table.ng-star-inserted').should('contain', product_update[i].product_code)
    }
    if(product_update[i].unit == null ) {
        cy.get('.ui-datatable-data > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(3)').should('contain', '')
    }
    else{
        cy.get('.top-aligned-table.ng-star-inserted').should('contain',product_update[i].unit)
    }
    if(product_update[i].product_category== null) {
        cy.get('.ui-datatable-data > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(4)').should('contain', '')
    }
    else{
        cy.get('.top-aligned-table.ng-star-inserted').should('contain', product_update[i].product_category)
    }
    if(product_update[i].purchase_price== null ) {
        cy.get('.ui-datatable-data > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(5)').should('contain', '')
    }
    else{
        cy.get('.top-aligned-table.ng-star-inserted').should('contain', product_update[i].purchase_price)
    }
    if(product_update[i].sales_price== null) {
        cy.get('.ui-datatable-data > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(7)').should('contain', '')
    }
    else{
        cy.get('.top-aligned-table.ng-star-inserted').should('contain', product_update[i].sales_price)
    }
    if(product_update[i].description== null) {
        cy.get('.ui-datatable-data > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(8)').should('contain', '')
    }
    else{
        cy.get('.top-aligned-table.ng-star-inserted').should('not.have.value', product_update[i].description)
    }


    cy.url().should('include','/invoicer/product')
    }


}




//file function
import {productupdate} from
'../test_func/product_update.js'

describe("Product", function(){
    
    beforeEach(function () {
      cy.login(); 
    });
    
    it("Update Product", function(){
        //Change partner type with Supplier or Client or Both
        var product_update=[{
          "product_name"      : "LCD Series Baru", 
          "product_code"      : "SER0", 
          "unit"              : null, 
          "product_category"  : null, 
          "purchase_price"    : null, 
          "sales_price"       : null, 
          "description"       : "Layar Seri 1", 
          "update_stock"      : null
          
        },
        {
          "product_name"      : "LCD", 
          "product_code"      : "BMW", 
          "unit"              : "Piece", 
          "product_category"  : "Television", 
          "purchase_price"    : "25555000", 
          "sales_price"       : "20,000", 
          "description"       : "Layar LCD", 
          "update_stock"      :"Stock"
        }
        
      
      
      ];
        
        productupdate(product_update);
        
 });
});
```

`